# Android where to initialize activity data?

Tags: java, android

I want to do initialization when activity starts.

I can put it in `onCreate` method, but it is called every time `screenOrientation` is changed.
I can disable this in `AndroidManifest`, but maybe there is better solution for this?

Comment: This is one of my biggest gripes about programming for android, I loathe screen orientation changes.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this [article about activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html), including [orientation change handling](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html). In general [reading about activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?q=activity%20lifecycle#Lifecycle) would also help you.